# Django - get linked models in many to many

Tags: django, django-models

I have two different models:

A group model

```
class Group(models.Model):
  (...)
  users=models.ManyToManyField(users.User, related_name='trainings')
```

And a very standard user model. 
I'm trying to write a function where it returns all of the linked groups for a given User object.

What would solve my problem is something like this:

```
def get_groups(user):
  connected_groups = Group.objects.filter(user in users)
```

But that throws an error. It the thing that I am trying possible? Or should I instead create a 'linked_groups' variable within the User model?

Comment: `connected_groups = Group.objects.filter(users__in=[user])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

> Both ends of a many-to-many relationship get automatic API access to the other end. The API works just as a “backward” one-to-many relationship, above.
>
> The only difference is in the attribute naming: The model that defines the ManyToManyField uses the attribute name of that field itself, whereas the “reverse” model uses the lowercased model name of the original model, plus '_set' (just like reverse one-to-many relationships).

For any `User` called `u` in your application, `u.group_set.all()` will be a queryset of all `Groups` with a many-to-many relationship to that user. Since you have defined a `related_name` you can use the more readable syntax `u.trainings.all()`.